# Insert linefeed in sed (Mac OS X)

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed

How do I insert a newline in the replacement part of sed?

This code isn't working:

```
sed "s/\(1234\)/\n\1/g" input.txt > output.txt
```

where input.txt is:

```
test1234foo123bar1234
```

and output.txt should be:

```
test
1234foo123bar
1234
```

but insted I get this:

```
testn1234foo123barn1234
```

**NOTE:**

This question is specifically about the Mac OS X version of "sed", and the community has noted that it behaves differently than, say, Linux versions.

Comment: Did you typo the example? I can't reproduce this "testn..." output; it looks like the \n is wrong in the right-hand-side of the s///

Comment: I can. It shows "testn" for me as well. Probably each system's sed interprets this in its own way.

Comment: @rdineiu, I think the problem is the way the backslash is passed with the quotes. I assume Tylio is using bash (from the question-tag); what do you get if you type `set -x; echo "n \n \\n"` ? Specifically, are the backslashes preserved?

Comment: I use bash as well. I get `n \n \n`. I tried replacing that `\n` with everything I could think of, including `\\n`, `\<CR><CR>`, `\<^V><CR>`, `\\<^V><CR>`. The only thing that worked was an explicit `\n\n\r` from an `echo`.

Comment: @Phil outputs: + echo 'n \n \n'    
n \n \n

Comment: OK, elsewhere you've said that this is sed on a Mac. I'd go with @prezemoc's FAQ entry or the perl snippet I gave.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Your sed version apparently does not support `\n` in RHS (right-hand side of substitution). You should read [THE SED FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq.html) maintained by Eric Pement to choose one of possible solutions. I suggest trying first inserting literal newline character.

Below is the quote from it.

---

**4.1. How do I insert a newline into the RHS of a substitution?**

Several versions of sed permit `\n` to be typed directly into the RHS, which is then converted to a newline on output: ssed, gsed302a+, gsed103 (with the `-x` switch), sed15+, sedmod, and UnixDOS sed. The easiest solution is to use one of these versions.

For other versions of sed, try one of the following:

**(a)** If typing the sed script from a Bourne shell, use one backslash `\` if the script uses 'single quotes' or two backslashes `\\` if the script requires "double quotes". In the example below, note that the leading `>` on the 2nd line is generated by the shell to prompt the user for more input. The user types in slash, single-quote, and then ENTER to terminate the command:

```
 [sh-prompt]$ echo twolines | sed 's/two/& new\
 >/'
 two new
 lines
 [bash-prompt]$
```

**(b)** Use a script file with one backslash `\` in the script, immediately followed by a newline. This will embed a newline into the "replace" portion. Example:

```
 sed -f newline.sed files

 # newline.sed
 s/twolines/two new\
 lines/g
```

Some versions of sed may not need the trailing backslash. If so, remove it.

**(c)** Insert an unused character and pipe the output through tr:

```
 echo twolines | sed 's/two/& new=/' | tr "=" "\n"   # produces
 two new
 lines
```

**(d)** Use the `G` command:

G appends a newline, plus the contents of the hold space to the end of the pattern space. If the hold space is empty, a newline is appended anyway. The newline is stored in the pattern space as `\n` where it can be addressed by grouping `\(...\)` and moved in the RHS. Thus, to change the "twolines" example used earlier, the following script will work:

```
 sed '/twolines/{G;s/\(two\)\(lines\)\(\n\)/\1\3\2/;}'
```

**(e)** Inserting full lines, not breaking lines up:

If one is not changing lines but only inserting complete lines before or after a pattern, the procedure is much easier. Use the `i` (insert) or `a` (append) command, making the alterations by an external script. To insert `This line is new` BEFORE each line matching a regex:

```
 /RE/i This line is new               # HHsed, sedmod, gsed 3.02a
 /RE/{x;s/$/This line is new/;G;}     # other seds
```

The two examples above are intended as "one-line" commands entered from the console. If using a sed script, `i\` immediately followed by a literal newline will work on all versions of sed. Furthermore, the command `s/$/This line is new/` will only work if the hold space is already empty (which it is by default).

To append `This line is new` AFTER each line matching a regex:

```
 /RE/a This line is new               # HHsed, sedmod, gsed 3.02a
 /RE/{G;s/$/This line is new/;}       # other seds
```

To append 2 blank lines after each line matching a regex:

```
 /RE/{G;G;}                    # assumes the hold space is empty
```

To replace each line matching a regex with 5 blank lines:

```
 /RE/{s/.*//;G;G;G;G;}         # assumes the hold space is empty
```

**(f)** Use the `y///` command if possible:

On some Unix versions of sed (not GNU sed!), though the `s///` command won't accept `\n` in the RHS, the `y///` command does. If your Unix sed supports it, a newline after `aaa` can be inserted this way (which is not portable to GNU sed or other seds):

```
 s/aaa/&~/; y/~/\n/;    # assuming no other '~' is on the line!
```

Comment: @Tyilo While I am happy that I was helpful, it's good to avoid executing other tools if it can be done w/o them, thus I suggest you to try all other ways too and then choose the best one suiting you.

Comment: @Tyilo This is *(a)*, so sorry, but I am not sure whether you tried them all, because you're contradicting yourself. Have you tried *(f)* for example?

Comment: As of at least GNU sed version 4.2.1, (f) works there, too. In fact, the `y` function with `\n` handling is part of POSIX: http://man.cx/sed

Answer (score 27):

Here's a **single-line solution that works with *any* POSIX-compatible `sed`** (including the FreeBSD version on macOS), **assuming your shell is `bash` or `ksh` or `zsh`**:

```
sed 's/\(1234\)/\'$'\n''\1/g' <<<'test1234foo123bar1234'
```

<sup>Note that you *could* use a *single* ANSI C-quoted string as the *entire* `sed` script, `sed $'...' <<<`, but that would necessitate `\`-escaping all `\` instances (doubling them), which is quite cumbersome and hinders readability, as evidenced by [@tovk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114931/45375)).</sup>

- `$'\n'` represents a newline and is an instance of **[ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)**, which allows you to create strings with control-character escape sequences.
- The above ***splices* the ANSI C-quoted string *into* the `sed` script** as follows:

  - The script is simply **broken into 2 single-quoted strings, with the ANSI C-quoted string stuck between the two halves**:
  - `'s/\(1234\)/\'` is the 1st half - note that it **ends in `\`, so as to escape the newline that will be inserted as the next char.** (this escaping is necessary to mark the newline as part of the replacement string rather than being interpreted as the end of the command).
  - `$'\n'` is the ANSI C-quoted representation of a newline character, **which the shell expands to an *actual* newline before passing the script to `sed`**.
  - `'\1/g'` is the 2nd half.

Note that this solution **works analogously for other control characters**, such as `$'\t'` to represent a tab character.

---

**Background info**:

- The POSIX `sed` specification: http://man.cx/sed

  - *BSD* `sed`  (also used on macOS) stays close to this spec, while *GNU* `sed` offers many extensions.
- A summary of the differences between *GNU* `sed` and *BSD* `sed` can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375

Comment: This is brilliant, and it also work with sh that comes with Freebsd

Comment: To make this work with double-quotes on OSX I did this:

`sed "s/\(1234\)/\\"$'\n'"\1/g" <<<'test1234foo123bar1234'`

Effectively means double-escaping the `"`.

Answer (score 9):

The solaris version of `sed` I could convince to work this way (in `bash`):

```
echo test1234foo123bar1234 | sed 's/\(1234\)/\
\1/g'
```

(you have to put the line break directly after the backslash).

In `csh` I had to put one more backslash:

```
echo test1234foo123bar1234 | sed 's/\(1234\)/\\
\1/g'
```

The Gnu version of `sed` simply worked using `\n`:

```
echo test1234foo123bar1234 | sed 's/\(1234\)/\n\1/g'
```

Comment: This is the way I have always done it.  I just tested bash on Mac OS X 10.6, and the first example works.

Comment: The first example, with a single \, doesn't work on my Mac OS X 10.6. The second one, with \\, does.

Comment: Oops, the command with double backslashes is working for me, thank you

Comment: First example works great on Mac OSX Lion.  Thanks for a SIMPLE answer.

Comment: If you have your sed expression in double quotes, then you also need double escaping \\ in bash (in osx)

Answer (score 8):

Perl provides a richer "extended" regex syntax which is useful here:

```
perl -p -e 's/(?=1234)/\n/g'
```

means "substitute a newline for the zero-width match following the pattern 1234". This avoids having to capture and repeat part the expression with backreferences.

Comment: This helped a lot in a Mac OS X server's shell. Instead of sed, perl becomes the "go to" tool for doing regex replace involving "insert a line return" work~

Answer (score 5):

Get a [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/).

```
$ brew install gnu-sed
```

Then your command will work as expected:

```
$ gsed "s/\(1234\)/\n\1/g" input.txt
test
1234foo123bar
1234
```

nb: you may get GNU sed thanks to mac ports too.

Comment: Well, this should be the accepted answer for macOS users. With `gnu-sed` I'm able to run my `script_file` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, for me, `sed` seems to ignore `\n`s in the replacement string.

```
$ echo test1234foo123bar1234 | sed "s/\(1234\)/\n\1/g"
testn1234foo123barn1234
```

If that happens for you as well, an alternative is to use:

```
$ echo test1234foo123bar1234 | sed "s/\(1234\)/\\`echo -e '\n\r'`\1/g"
```

This should work anywhere and will produce:

```
test
1234foo123bar
1234
```

For your example with an `input.txt` file as input and `output.txt` as output, use:

```
$ sed "s/\(1234\)/\\`echo -e '\n\r'`\1/g" input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, it works in terminal output, but when saving it to a file

Comment: Use sed "s/\(1234\)/\\`echo -e '\n\r'`\1/g" input.txt > output.txt to save to a file. It will work the same way.

Comment: But i don't want the carriage return, only line feed

Comment: Introducing CR (\r) characters isn't going to help. Superficially it might force a break on the terminal, but anything else which handles the data isn't going to expect, or deal with, LFCR line endings. In fact, nothing uses LFCR line endings other than the Acorn BBC, according to Wikipedia :)

Comment: @Phil, indeed, you're right. @Tyilo, Check bmk's answer. The part with \\<ENTER>\1/g should work correctly on the Mac. If you do want portability though, the perl solution is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ echo test1234foo123bar1234 | sed "s/\(1234\)/\n\1/g"
test
1234foo123bar
1234
```

From [Sed Gnu doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html)

```
g
    Apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first.
```

Comment: Sorry missed the g part, but the problem is displaying the linefeed

Comment: And output is still: testn1234foo123barn1234

Comment: @Tylio Works for me, as can be seen in my answer. I'm using GNU sed version 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 10.04. What system are you on?

Comment: @Tyilo I'm also on a Mac. Must be a Mac specific thing then. See my answer or Phil's, if you have no problem using perl instead of sed (perl's regexps are way more advanced and work the same way on all systems).

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the `$'string'` feature of Bash:

```
man bash | less -p "\\$'"

printf  '%s' 'test1234foo123bar1234'  | sed $'s/\\(1234\\)/\\\n\\1/g'
```

Comment: Neat trick with `less -p`; the `$'...'` feature is called [ANSI C-quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

Answer (score 1):

The newline in the middle of the command can feel a bit clumsy:

```
$ echo abc | sed 's/b/\
/'
a
c
```

Here are two solutions to this problem which I think should be quite portable
(should work for any POSIX-compliant `sh`, `printf`, and `sed`):

**Solution 1:**

Remember to escape any `\` and `%` characters for `printf` here:

```
$ echo abc | sed "$(printf 's/b/\\\n/')"
a
c
```

To avoid the need for escaping `\` and `%` characters for `printf`:

```
$ echo abc | sed "$(printf '%s\n%s' 's/b/\' '/')"
a
c
```

**Solution 2:**

Make a variable containing a newline like this:

```
newline="$(printf '\nx')"; newline="${newline%x}"
```

Or like this:

```
newline='
'
```

Then use it like this:

```
$ echo abc | sed "s/b/\\${newline}/"
a
c
```