# sed append line on 1 occurrence only

Tags: sed

Have this file

```
ServerName *
ServerAlias *
ServerAlias *

<Directory>
```

I want to append a new line after the first occurrence of ServerAlias with the text S2.
I have tried the following

```
sed '/ServerAlias/ a\S2\' foo
```

But this appends after all the occurrences.

My final result should be

```
ServerName *
ServerAlias *
S2
ServerAlias *

<Directory>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it's not sed, but maybe awk can help you.

```
$> cat ./file
ServerName *
ServerAlias *
ServerAlias *

<Directory>

$> awk '{print} /^ServerAlias/ && !n {print "S2"; n++}' ./file
ServerName *
ServerAlias *
S2
ServerAlias *

<Directory>
```

**UPD**: mistake is fixed now, thanks glenn_jackman

Comment: You'd probably need to anchor the regexp to avoid matching "ServerAlias" in comments.

Comment: To avoid printing the matched line twice, use: `awk '{print} /^ServerAlias/ && !n {print "S2"; n++}' file`

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for great observation.

Answer (score 2):

The awk solution above is best, but if you really want to do it in (GNU) sed then the following does the trick:

```
sed '0,/^ServerAlias.\+/s//\0\nS2/' file
```

Credit goes to [the sed FAQ](http://linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_004.html).

Comment: It was some buggy if I repeated the command multiple times. Probably, it depends from OS lindendings. Instead, I used ServerName as a target, to add a ServerAlias after.

Comment: Related to the potential line ending issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111679/insert-linefeed-in-sed