# sed insert line command OSX

Tags: regex, macos, sed, insert

I'm trying to insert text to the third line in a file using sed, and the syntax I've found on other forums is:

```
sed -i '' "3i\ text to insert" file
```

When I use this however, I get an error:

```
sed: 1: "3i\ text to insert": extra characters after \ at the end of i command
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing the problem. I'm using OSX, which is why I have an empty ' ' as my extension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should put a newline directly after the `\`:

```
sed '3i\
text to insert' file
```

This is actually the behaviour defined by the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). The fact that GNU sed allows you to specify the text to be inserted on the same line is an extension.

---

If for some reason you need to use double quotes around the sed command, then you must escape the backslash at the end of the first line:

```
sed "3i\\
text to insert" file
```

This is because a double-quoted string is processed first by the shell, and `\` followed by a newline is removed:

```
$ echo "abc\
def"
abcdef
```

Comment: I'd like to give an extra +1 for pointing out that the 'inserted text after the `3i` bit' is a GNU extension (but I can only give one of them).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'll award him the other +1 on your behalf :-)

Answer (score 21):

On OSX you can use:

```
sed -i.bak '3i\
text to insert
' file
```

Answer (score 12):

A one-liner for OSX employing ANSI-C quoting:

```
sed -i '' '3i\'$'\n''text to insert' file
```

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/24299845/901597

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to do it in one line syntax

```
sed -i '' -e "2s/^//p; 2s/^.*/text to insert/" file
```

- duplicate second line: `2s/^//p;`
- replace new line with your text: `2s/^.*/text to insert/`

Comment: I believe this approach will work to add a line between any two lines n and n+1. However, attempting this against the very first line you encounter problems described in [another post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99350/how-to-insert-text-before-the-first-line-of-a-file)

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

```
sed -i '' '3i\
text to insert' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I have to insert a \ at the end of the line to be inserted, otherwise it concatenates it at the beginning of the original line. So, if I want to insert a new third line,...

```
sed -i '' '3i\<br>
New line to be inserted.\<br>
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a file of specific file type(.sh in my case) use this command.

```
sed -i '.sh' '3i\
mymodified text to insert' temp.sh
```

Make sure you have line break after slash ("\")

Answer (score 0):

To insert text to the first line and put the rest on a new line using sed on macOS this worked for me

```sh
sed -i '' '1 i \
Insert
' ~/Downloads/File-path.txt
```