# extra characters after \ at the end of a command

Tags: macos, sed

When I try to insert new line in OSX using sed I'm getting the below error

> extra characters after \ at the end of a command

Current File content is

```
{
'localhost' => ['domain_name' => 'default', 'domain_type' => 'mobile'],
}
```

Expected content is

```
{
'localhost' => ['domain_name' => 'default', 'domain_type' => 'mobile'],
 'dev.ops' => ['domain_name' => 'default', 'domain_type' => 'mobile'],
}
```

The command I'm using is

```
sed -i '' "/localhost/a\                        'dev.ops' => ['domain_name' => 'default', 'domain_type' => 'web']," FILENAME
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed insert line command OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631989/sed-insert-line-command-osx)

Answer (score 28):

**BSD/macOS `sed` requires an *actual newline character* to follow `a\`**, before the text to append:

```sh
sed -i '' "/localhost/ a\\
                        'dev.ops' => ['domain_name' => 'default', 'domain_type' => 'web'],
" FILENAME
```

- Since you're using `"..."` to enclose your `sed` script, `a\` must be represented as `a\\` so that the `\` is not mistaken for a line continuation character.

  - It is generally better to use `'...'` to enclose your script argument, but here the use of `"..."` is convenient for easy embedding of `'` instances.

<sup>As an aside: GNU `sed` - installable on macOS via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) using `brew install gnu-sed` - offers more features and more convenient syntax - notably, no need for a newline to follow the `a` function; for a discussion of all differences between BSD/macOS `sed` and GNU `sed`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375) of mine.</sup>

Comment: I solved this problem permanently by installing gnu-sed.

brew install gnu-sed

and use "gnu-sed" as "sed" by adding a "gnubin" directory to PATH from ~/.bash_profile like this:

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin:$PATH".

Thanks @mklement0

Answer (score 3):

Use sed `p` command to copy line and then replace the

```
sed '/localhost/p; s/localhost/dev.ops/' FILENAME
```

outputs

```
{
'localhost' => ['domain_name' => 'default', 'domain_type' => 'mobile'],
'devops' => ['domain_name' => 'default', 'domain_type' => 'mobile'],
}
```

or to edit in place on OSX without keeping a backup, use `-i ''`:

```
sed -i '' -e '/localhost/p; s/localhost/dev.ops/' FILENAME
```