# Bash - Comment out a specific line that partly matches a string in a file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with an argument

```
testArgument=
```

It could have something equal to it or nothing but I want to comment it and add the new line with supplied info

Before:

```
testArgument=Something
```

Results:

```
#testVariable=Something

#Comments to let the user know of why the change
testVariable=NewSomething
```

Should I loop it or should I use something like `sed`?  I need it to be compatible for Ubuntu and Debian and bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sed like this:

```
sed 's/^\(testArgument\)=.*/#&\n\n#Comment here\n\1=NewSomething/' file
```

`&` prints the full match in the replacement and `\1` refers to the first capture group "testArgument".

To perform the substitution on the file in-place (i.e. replace the contents of the original file), add the `-i` switch. Otherwise, if you want to output the command to a new file, do `sed '...' file > newfile`.

If you are using a different version of sed that doesn't support `\n` newlines in the replacement, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111679/insert-linefeed-in-sed-mac-os-x) for some ways to deal with it.

Alternatively, using GNU awk:

```
gawk '/^testArgument/ {$0 = gensub(/^(testArgument)=.*/, "#\\0\n\n#Comment here\n\\1=NewSomething", 1)}1' file
```

Comment: What you mean by "file in-place"?  I need to keep the same file because there is other data in the file.  Does this make a new file?

Comment: Can I add additional requirement? Might make it harder. The 'testArgument' might be commented already so in that case then just add the new line under the that line. But if isn't commented then comment and add the new line afterwards.

Comment: O i mess this up.  Theres no equals in my file after the argument. I guess I can rewrite your statement with this sed 's/^\(testArgument\).*/#&\n\n#Comment here\n\1 NewSomething/' file

Comment: That's probably because your version of seed doesn't support newline characters in the replacement string. The question I linked to explains how to deal with that.

Comment: If you got a chance, take a look at this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952293/bash-find-and-replace-with-new-lines-in-the-same-file  Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

```
awk '/^testArugment/ {$0="#"$0"\n\n#Comments to let the user know of why the change\ntestVariable=NewSomething"}1' file
```

```
cat file
some data
testArugment=Something
more data

awk '/^testArugment/ {$0="#"$0"\n\n#Comments to let the user know of why the change\ntestVariable=NewSomething"}1' file
some data
#testArugment=Something

#Comments to let the user know of why the change
testVariable=NewSomething
more data
```

---

To change the original file

```
awk 'code....' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```