# Bash - Find and replace with new lines in the same file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to find a line in a file that contains a specific variable name. This variable may be commented or not.  If not commented then I need to comment it.  Add two lines afterwards. The first line begins with a comment on why the addition of the new line then the new line of the variable with attach value.  I'm using ubuntu 14.04.01 x64 and it has version (GNU sed) 4.2.2 and GNU Awk 4.0.1 .  Also I would like to use variable defined earlier in the script. So command needs to be accept reference to those variables. Also do not output the result to console. Some examples are:

Case 1

```
#ssh_param /path/to/file
```

Results

```
#ssh_param /path/to/file

#New path defined
ssh_param /etc/ssh/file
```

Case 2

```
ssh_param /path/to/file
```

Result

```
#ssh_param /path/to/file

#New path defined
ssh_param /etc/ssh/file
```

Case 3

```
#ssh_param
```

Results

```
#ssh_param 

#New path defined
ssh_param /etc/ssh/file
```

Case 4

```
#ssh_param dasfda
ssh_param /path/to/file
```

Results

```
#ssh_param dasfda
#ssh_param /path/to/file 

#New path defined
ssh_param /etc/ssh/file
```

Comment: What if there are multiple instances of the line?

Comment: There needs to be only one uncommented one which is one i'm adding...thats important. The rest needs to be commented.

Comment: Maybe I should just replace the line if I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanted to use "variables defined earlier in the script."  Here are the variables:

```
file="path/to/input/file"
var="ssh_param"
msg="#New path defined"
new="/etc/ssh/file"
```

Here are the commands which use those variables:

```
lineno=$(grep -n "$var" "$file" | tail -n1 | sed 's/:.*//')
if [ "$lineno" ]
then
    sed -i -r "$lineno s|#?(.*)|#\1\n$msg\n$var $new|" "$file"
else
    sed -i -r "$ s|$|\n$msg\n$var $new|" "$file"
fi
```

Notes:

- It appears from your examples that the variable name may occur multiple times in the script but only the last one is uncommented.  We use that here to simplify the code.  The line number of the last appearance of the variable in the script is found from:

  ```
  lineno=$(grep -n "$var" "$file" | tail -n1 | sed 's/:.*//')
  ```

  The `grep -n` part finds a list of line numbers on which the variable name occurs.  `tail -n1` returns only the last such line.  The `sed` command removes all but the line number from the output.
- The substitution is done by this command:

  ```
  sed -i -r "$lineno s|#?(.*)|#\1\n$msg\n$var $new|" "$file"`
  ```

  This uses sed's ability to operate on a particular line number.  That line is substituted by three lines: the first is a copy of the existing line but commented, the second is the message, and the third is the new definition of the variable.
- If the variable is not currently in the file, then `lineno` is empty.  In this case, we want to add the new lines to the end of the file.  This is done via a similar but simpler `sed` command:

  ```
  sed -i -r "$ s|$|\n$msg\n$var $new|" "$file"
  ```

The first `$` tells `sed` to operate only on the last line.  The second`$` appears in the substitute command where it signifies the end of that line.  Your message and new variable definition are appended.

#### Example

With this as the input:

```
#ssh_param dasfda
ssh_param /path/to/file
```

The above code replaces the file with:

```
#ssh_param dasfda
#ssh_param /path/to/file
#New path defined
ssh_param /etc/ssh/file
```

(If you want blank lines to space things out, just add some `\n` to the `sed` output expression.)

Comment: The only problem I see is when there is no reference to the var, it then overwrites everything and the file is destroyed . If that's the case, I would want to add the line to end of the file.  It overwrites everything and destroys the file.   The input variable for the grep is the file so it might be better to call input file.

Comment: @user3590149 I added a line to handle that special case.  I also corrected a typo in the `lineno` line.

Comment: k...good stuff.  I have one issue maybe not with your solution. I use your solution in a function and excluding the last time the function is called. Every line that was inserted has a comment.  I trying to get a code review.  Please refer to my code in reference to this.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63456/updating-a-config-file

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'index($0, "ssh_param /path/to/file"){if (substr($0, 1, 1) != "#") $0 = "#" $0;
       $0=$0 "\n\n#New path defined\nssh_param /etc/ssh/file"} 1' file
```

**To change fil content:**

```
awk 'index($0, "ssh_param /path/to/file"){if (substr($0, 1, 1) != "#") $0 = "#" $0;
       $0=$0 "\n\n#New path defined\nssh_param /etc/ssh/file"} 1' file > file.tmp
mv file.tmp > file
```

Comment: The file doesn't get updated with your example. I an output onto console that shows the changes but file doesn't change.  I need to update the file and also suppress the output if possible

Comment: I added to your command at the end, '> tmp && mv tmp file'  But it doesn't work for multiple instances. You get weird results.

Comment: Maybe I should just replace the line if I find it?

Comment: Check updated answer for changing content in the file itself. I have tested this awk code with all your inputs and it worked fine.