# Removing HTML Tags from a text file

Tags: bash

I have a bit of html that looks like this:

```
`<p>Flannel</p><p>Plaid</p><p>Red</p>`
```

I want to strip the `<p>` and `</p>` tags and replace with a newline character so I end up with something like this:

```
Flannel
Plaid
Red
```

I am attempting to use this `tr` command:

```
tr '<[^>]*>' '\n'
```

but it is only removing the outer `<` and `>`, so I end up with this instead:

```
p
Flannel
/p

p
Plaid
/p

p
Red
/p
```

How can I modify it to remove the entire tag?

Note: I don't care if I end up with multiple newlines between the entires, those are easy to strip away later if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
echo "<p>Flannel</p><p>Plaid</p><p>Red</p>"|awk '{gsub(/<[^>]*>/,"\n"); print }'

Flannel

Plaid

Red
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless this is a quick-and-dirty script, you should definitely use an HTML parser to handle all the intricacies of the HTML language.

A quick-and-dirty solution could be to apply this `sed` command :

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>/\n/g'
```

I think it does what you need with your specific example :

```
$ echo "<p>Flannel</p><p>Plaid</p><p>Red</p>" | sed 's/<[^>]*>/\n/g'

Flannel

Plaid

Red
```

Your solution doesn't work because `tr` doesn't work on strings but on characters : it's simply replacing every `<[^>]*` characters it finds, disregarding the fact you attempted to write a regular expression.

Comment: I was previously trying `sed` and it would correctly find the tags, but it would only replace them with either n or the actual character `\n` as opposed to a new line.  The only version I found that worked was this: `sed "s/<[^>]*>/\\`echo -e '\n\r'`/g"` which gave me the newline I wanted, but included the funky ^M character too.

Comment: @CarrieBrown so, my solution doesn't work on your end?

Comment: `echo -e '\n\r'` is weird, I don't know any systems which would use this style of linefeed. Removing the `\r` (which is what is displayed as `^M`) might be enough to solve your problem, but you shouldn't need to invoke a subshell to produce a line feed. If `\n` from my answer doesn't work, replace it by a literal linefeed.

Comment: I tried removing the \r and it didn't work either. I will try the literal.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111679/insert-linefeed-in-sed-mac-os-x)'s another question on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

Put them all inside the same

```html
<p>
```

tag, then use 
 tags between each one to add a line break.
So, the code should be something like this:

```html
<p>Flannel<br>Plaid<br>Red</p>
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. I want the resulting file to be free of all HTML and just be raw text. It's a fairly large file, so editing the tags manually isn't feasible.